# Display android DrawerLayout in Xamarin xml designer

Tags: android, xamarin, drawerlayout

I have Xamaring project and some `.axml` layout with structure like that:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >
    <LinearLayout >
        <ImageButton />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout >
        <Button />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It works perfect on the device, but I can't view the content inside the Xamarin designer tool.

Is it possible to fix it? Android Studio displays this case fine.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: As far as I know this is default behaviour for drawer layout. You can set the required properties in source tab.

Comment: Android studio displays drawer fine, with all the content inside the both parts of the drawer